# WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally error running Selenium Grid on Server using ChromeDriver and Chrome

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

Good evening,

I tried to run my automated tests on a server with Eclipse / Selenium and TestNG. So far the configuration of Selenium Grid worked fine. I got the response:

```
23:02:55.068 INFO - Selenium Grid hub is up and running
23:03:30.488 INFO - Registered a node http://81.169.xxx.xxx:5555 <br>
23:05:25.423 INFO - Registering the node to the hub: http://81.169.xxx.xxx:4444/grid/register
23:05:25.432 INFO - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
```

Here's my example code:

```
@Test
public void executeOnServer() throws MalformedURLException {
    System.out.println("Test started");
    DesiredCapabilities dcp = new DesiredCapabilities();
    dcp.setBrowserName("chrome");
    dcp.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://81.169.xxx.xxx:5555/wd/hub/"), dcp);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://google.de");
    driver.quit();
}
```

Unfortunately I got the error:

```
    [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
Test started
FAILED: executeOnServer
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: **Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.**
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'h28xxxxx.stratoserver.net', ip: '81.169.xxx.xxx', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0', java.version: '1.8.0_252'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: #0 0x559967ec9ea9 <unknown>
```

The path to the chromedriver is:

```
usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

Installed version:

```
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=**84.0.4147.30**/chromedriver_linux64.zip
```

Do you have any idea how I could fix the error? Had a look at different sites with this error, no solution is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
Test started
FAILED: executeOnServer
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: **Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.**
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'h28xxxxx.stratoserver.net', ip: '81.169.xxx.xxx', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0', java.version: '1.8.0_252'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: #0 0x559967ec9ea9 <unknown>
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=84.0*
- Possibly you are using the latest *chrome=84.0*
- Your *Selenium Client* version is *3.4.0* of `revision: 'unknown'`, `time: 'unknown'`

So that implies the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) is unable to interact with the [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) bindings as there is a clear mismatch between *Selenium v3.4.0* and the *ChromeDriver v84.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v84.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=84.0.4147.30/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 84.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v84.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/84.0.4147.30/notes.txt))
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.